# Ingreso por parámetro con IN()

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Tengo una función y el parámetro es el contenido del operador `IN()`.

Ejemplo:
esta es la consulta, pero yo quiero enviar una cadena en el operador `in()`

```sql
 select * 
 from miTablax t
 where t.pais in ('argentina','españa','portugal');
 -- where t.pais in (pIngreso)
```

He intentado esto pero no funciona.

```sql
pIngreso = 'argentina'||','||'españa'||','||'portugal'
```

Comment: No te ha funcionado quitándole el paréntesis? Dejándolo solo como `WHERE t.pais IN pIngreso` ? y declara el `pIngreso = 'Argentina,España,Portugal'`

Comment: acabo de probar pero no me devuelve la información

Comment: ¿Es estrictamente necesario que sea con `IN()`? ¿Podrías utilizar otras funciones en su lugar?

Comment: No es necesario, pero no se como puedo realizar ese tipo de filtro al ser variable. 

que funciones habías pensado?

Comment: Se me ocurre esto: crea una tabla temporal, crea una columna que se llame Country (o como quieras para que la identifiques), llena los datos ahí antes de ejecutar la función (Argentina, España y Portugal) y en el `IN` trabájalo como subquery, algo así: `IN (SELECT Country FROM TablaTemp)`. No sé que tan eficiente sea, pero de que te sirve, te sirve.

Comment: Hooo si queda, muchas gracias.